# Separate internal errors from client errors in custom WCF error handling?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that implements custom error handling by implementing the IErrorHandler interface.

Now, if a client sends a request with an invalid XML structure the serializer will throw an InvalidOperationException and we end up in the custom error handler.
However, an InvalidOperationException seems like a pretty general exception to me and I'm worried that the server might throw such an exception while processing the request (should only happen in truly exceptional cases, but some weird state might produce such an exception).

These are two different errors and should result in two different StatusCodes set to the response. How can I reliably identify the source of an exception so that I can set the proper StatusCode in my custom error handler?

Comment: Can you differentiate using the inner exception? hopefully the serializer exception has some more specific inner exception that would help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the exception that is thrown by the serializer for invalid XML is an InvalidOperationException with inner exception of type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException`

If you detect this, you can do the required error specific processing. For example:

```
public bool HandleError(Exception error)
{
   string output = "Unknown error";

   if (error.InnerException is System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException)
   {
      output = "Malformed message";
   }

   TraceSource traceSource = new TraceSource("YourTraceSource");
   traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, output);

   return false;
}
```

Or

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    if (error.InnerException is System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException)
    {
       //set malformed message status code (400?)
    }
    else
    {
       //set other status code
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The inner exception is actually a System.Xml.XmlException, but the source is System.Runtime.Serialization which makes it possible to detect a serialization error, so I'll mark your answer as correct and edit it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own exception class by deriving from `System.Exception` and throwing them where your validation fails. In your `IErrorHandler` implementation you should check if the exception is yours and return the Status code you want. For example if `MyException` was the derived exception:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
   MyException me = error as MyException;
      if(me != null)
          // Set the status code.
}
```

Comment: If I knew exactly where and when exceptions could appear, then yes I would implement custom exceptions (and so I have in quite a few places). But the problem is that a System.InvalidOperationException is not something I except, so it's unfortunately not possible to anticipate where it'll happen and thus not possible to catch.